# ios corebluetooth reconnect device after close app without call cancelPeripheralConnection

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

The follow:

1. Open my app
2. Scan device -> paring -> connecting -> write some setting information. It's successful.
3. Double tap on home button and remove app.
4. I see the in Bluetooth menu in **Setting app** that my device is still connecting. If I turn my device off then turn it on, the **Setting app** will connect my device. It seems **Setting app** try to re-connect to paired device.
5. Open my app again, then retrieve peripherals:

   **[centralManager retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:servicesUUID];**

   Result:

   **CBPeripheral: 0x14d741b0, identifier = 3E0A0FE9-33DB-D2FC-90CE-B73AB64045DB, name = Time App, state = disconnected**
6. Connect to retrieved peripheral, but system didn't trigger any callback: **didFailToConnectPeripheral** or **didConnectPeripheral**.
7. I try to use Preservation and Restoration, but **UIApplicationLaunchOptionsBluetoothCentralsKey** always return **null**.

   So, How to I connect to my device after closing app without call **cancelPeripheralConnection**? At this time, I must go to **Setting app**, then forget my device to connect it again.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are only calling `[centralManager retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:servicesUUID];` and `connectPeripheral` after the central manager state delegate method returns CBCentralManagerStateConnected. If you attempt a connection to the peripheral before the central manager has been fully initialized, it will not connect.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the peripheral delegate appropriately?

```
peripheral.delegate = self;
```